# Multiple CDI configuration profiles (devel, beta, qa, production) in one war?

Tags: java, spring, java-ee-6, cdi

Having experience with the Spring DI applicationContext.xml way of declaring Dependency Injection I now try to figure out how to do the same with Java EE6 CDI.

With Spring, I could ship my .jar with several configuration profiles like
*unittest.xml, devel.xml, qa.xml, production.xml* and activate them using command line parameters or environment variables.

With CDI, I could use @Alternative in *beans.xml* and properties in  of *web.xml* but there seems no way of shipping multiple beans.xml for different environments.

I don't want to use Maven profiles/filters to produce 4-6 versions of my app although I understand that for some scenarios that would be the better solution (i.e. shipping ready build wars to customers - but I only use my wars internally so let's save compile time!)

Preferably, I would also be able to load those configuration files from the file system so that they could be edited by the sysadmins without having to re-build the app.

What is the Java EE6 way of having multiple configuration sets of dependencies and properties?

If there is none, what are the recommended alternatives as of 2013? Using Spring? Seam? Guice? I saw mentionings of Apache DeltaSpike but they still seem alpha juding from the web page.

Comment: I suggest not giving the sysadmins the ability to change everything. Let them change a selected subset. OK. But not everything or you will someday spend a long time debugging a mistake they made that you can't reproduce.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd use a dynamic producer, using a `Qualifier` to identify the desired environment

```
// The qualifier for the production/qa/unit test 
@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD,
 ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Stage {
   String value() default "production";
}

// The interface for the stage-dependant service
public interface Greeting{
    public String sayHello();
}

// The production service
@Stage("production")
public class ProductionGreeting implements Greeting{
    public String sayHello(){return "Hello customer"; }
}

// The QA service
@Stage("qa")
public class QAGreeting implements Greeting{
    public String sayHello(){return "Hello tester"; }
}

// The common code wich uses the service
@Stateless
public class Salutation{
   @Inject Greeting greeting; 
   public String sayHello(){ return greeting.sayHello(); };
}

// The dynamic producer
public class GreetingFactory{
    @Inject
    @Any
    Instance<Greeting> greetings;        

    public String getEnvironment(){
         return System.getProperty("deployenv");
    }

    @Produces
    public Greeting getGreeting(){
        Instance<Greeting> found=greetings.select(
           new StageQualifier(getEnvironment()));
        if (!found.isUnsatisfied() && !found.isAmbiguous()){
           return found.get();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Error ...");
    }

    public static class StageQualifier 
      extends AnnotationLiteral<Stage> 
      implements Stage {
       private String value;

       public StageQualifier(String value){
           this.value=value;
       }
       public String value() { return value; }
     }

}
```

So here the container injects all available `Greeting` implementations into `GreetingFactory`, which in turn serves as `@Producer` for the intended one, basing the decision on the system property 'deployenv'.

Comment: Thanks for the example source code. It's an interesing example for @Produces, it seems I would have to write a Factory for every class that exists in multiple variations and that could be a few. It would also get messy if I have a dozend "@Inject String password" variables as I would have to use qualifiers to differentiate the several String types. So it does not seem to scale for for big applications, or?

Comment: Well, it's the price to pay to type safeness... Besides, the `@Stage` qualifier could be used for all your configurable types, the same could be said for the  `GreetingFactory` which could produce all the dynamically injectable beans. As for the  `@Inject String password`, you could introduce a single qualifier, defining the origin property as in `@Inject @Config("db.password") String password`. Another (more drastic) approach could be leveraging the portable extension API.

Comment: How do you switch between stages in your code? In other words, where is the stage defined/configured and what file does the maven build need to change?

Comment: In the code above it is done in the `GreetingFactory` by the method  `getEnvironment()`. In the sample it's a simple system property, but in the method you can load a property file.

Answer (score 2):

The above answer by Carlo is good, we have all of this in DeltaSpike [with the ProjectStage](http://deltaspike.apache.org/deltaspike/core.html#type-safe-projectstage). Worth taking a look at so you don't have to write it all yourself.

Comment: The _@Exclude(exceptIf=Development.class) @Alternative_ approach looked promising but often different project stages use the same class but with different properties (username/passwords), how will they get injected? The documentation only says "TODO" :)
I want that in some kind of externally editable .properties or .xml files and not as public final files in a compiled Java class.

As you wrote "we": should I open a Jira ticket with a wishlist? :)

Comment: You're certainly welcome to open a JIRA ticket, subscribe to our [user list][mailto:users-subscribe@deltaspike.apache.org], or visit us in IRC #deltaspike. What you're looking for there would be the configuration piece, you can find that in the same documentation I linked to earlier.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is suggested by M.-Leander Reimer in his presentation [Migrating a JSF-Based Web Application from Spring 3 to Java EE 7 and CDI](https://speakerdeck.com/lreimer/migrating-a-jsf-based-web-application-from-spring-3-to-java-ee-7-and-cdi) (Slide 32), using a CDI extension:

```
@Alternative
@Stereotype
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ProfileAlternative {
    Profile[] value();
}

public void processAnnotated(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<?> event) {
    ProfileAlternative pa = getProfileAlternative(event);
    if (profileAlternativeIsNotActive(pa)) {
        event.veto();
    }
 }
```

He uses a custom annotation `@ProfileAlternative` mimicking Spring's `@Profile` and a CDI extension observing the `ProcessAnnotatedType` event to `veto()` the type if it is annotated with a profile and the profile is not active.