# Java CDI: How to change producers at runtime using qualifiers with multiple values?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I need to change how JDBC Connections are injected depending on the environment (development, test, production, etc.) where my application is executed. 
Addition of new environments has to handled easely. Therefore, I am trying to implement this kind of behaviour considering Pellegrini's  solution to the following question:

[Multiple CDI configuration profiles (devel, beta, qa, production) in one war?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16907185/multiple-cdi-configuration-profiles-devel-beta-qa-production-in-one-war)

However, my context is a little bit different. Let's see:

Injection points are like this:

```
@Inject 
private Connection conn;
```

I have two connection factories:

1. **ConnectionFactory**: Used for test, acceptance and production environments;
2. **ProxyConnectionFactory**: Just for development environments.

Their definitions look like these:

```
public inteface ConnectionFactory {
  public Connection getConnection();
}

@Environment({ "test", "acceptance", "production" })
public CustomConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory {
  public Connection getConnection() {
    // Implementation code
  }
}

@Environment({ "development" })
public ProxyCustomConnectionFactory implements ConnectionFactory {
  public Connection getConnection() {
    // Implementation code
  }
}

@Qualifier
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Environment {
    String[] value() default {"production"};
}
```

Finally, my producer code that uses one of the previous factories to produce an appropriate connection for each intended environment:

```
public class ConnectionProducer {

  @Inject
  @Any
  Instance<ConnectionFacotry> connectionFactories;   

  public String getEnvironment(){
    return System.getProperty("deploy-environment");
  }

  @Produces
  public Connection produceConnection(){

    String[] profile = {getEnvironment().toLowerCase()};

    Instance<ConnectionFactory> found = connectionFactories.select(
      new EnvironmentQualifier(profile));
        if (!found.isUnsatisfied() && !found.isAmbiguous()){
          return found.get();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Error ...");
    }

    public static class EnvironmentQualifier 
      extends AnnotationLiteral<Environment> 
      implements Environment {      
      private String[] value;      
      public EnvironmentQualifier(String[] value) {
        this.value=value;      
      }             
      public String[] value() { return value; }
    }    

  }
```

This code is raising a runtime error because the instruction `found.isAmbiguous()` evaluates true. I am not sure, but I think this issue occurs because the Environment qualifier accepts multiples values. What am I doing wrong?

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look At the [deltaspike project stage feature](https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/projectstage.html). This seems to be a good basis for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I am going to take a look at it. By the way, let me know. Do you have already used it? Is it easy to use? I am woried about its learning curve.

Comment: Deltaspike is the defacto standard for cdi extension. I mainly use the data module for my projects. You can pick snd choose whatever extension you need. The project stage is trivial to use, I personally set my env through system variable and dynamically use beans with @Exclude annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well your code. But, regarding your question, you can get one factory and in runtime inject the correct dependency depending of environment type specified.

For example, your annotation looks like this:

```
@Qualifier
@Rentention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD, TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER)
public @interface Environment {
    EnvironmentType environment() default EnvironmentType.PRODUCTION;

    public enum EnvironmentType {
        DEVELOPMENT,
        TEST,
        ACCEPTANCE,
        PRODUCTION;
    }
}
```

And in your producer method you can get the annotation of the bean to inject, extract the selected environment and eval it:

```
@Produces @Environment
public Connection getConnection(InjectionPoint ip) {
    Annotated annotated = ip.getAnnotated();
    Environment annotation = annotated.getAnnotation(Environment.class);
    EnvironmentType environment = annotation.environment();

    if(environment == EnvironmentType.DEVELOPMENT) {
        // return connection for development
    } else if(environment == EnvironmentType.TEST) {
        // return connection for production
    } else if(environment == EnvironmentType.ACCEPTANCE) {
        // return connection for acceptance
    } else {
        // return connection for production
    }
}
```

If I'm misunderstang, I'm sorry.

PD: Excuse my english

Comment: This is a valid solution, but I am looking for something that can be more "open to change". Now I have realized that even this approach that I have written doesn't ensure such a property. Imagine if a new kind of environment is created. We will need to change the producer code. It would be  better if we could provide a new producer and just set to the Environment qualifier a value matching this new environment. To do so, I will updade my sample code and remove the Profile enum.